# navigate screen overlaying with other screen

Tags: react-native

hello I am new to react native I am facing an abnormal behavior on navigation which happens between two modal screens first modal screen  as shown in the picture on navigate it goes into next screen works fine

[image]
here is second modal picture on navigate
[image]
problem comes when I press on div upload cnic picture front and back then screens getting merged both are different component , previous screen modal appear as you seen in photo I marked in the screen  with two modal screens
[image]
here is my CNIC upload screen code

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        displayModal(!modalVisible);
      }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
          onSwipeComplete={() => setModalVisible(false)}
          swipeDirection={['down']}
          useNativeDriverForBackdrop
          style={{margin: 0}}
          isVisible={modalVisible}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
              borderTopRightRadius: 25,
              marginTop:
                steper === 'step' ? deviceHeight * 0.1 : deviceHeight * 0.2,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                // alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 3,
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
              }}>
              <View style={{width: '100%', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <PopupBorder />
              </View>

              {/* first half */}
              <View
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  height: '18%',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                }}>
                <View style={styles.subContainer}>
                  <Image
                    style={{width: '40%', height: '50%', resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                    source={require('../assests/finger-print.png')}
                  />
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>Verify your account </Text>
                  <SubTitle
                    amount
                    color="#636363"
                    title="We require CNIC and Selfie for the verification"
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
              {/* steper */}
              <View
                style={{
                  height: '10%',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <DocumentSteper step={steper} />
              </View>

              {/* steper */}

              {/* second half */}
              <View
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '70%',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <View style={styles.subContainer}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                      width: '100%',
                      height: '80%',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}>
                    {steper === 'step' ? (
                      <>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          activeOpacity={0.6}
                          onPress={takeFrontPhotoFromCamera}
                          style={styles.imageContainer}>
                          <ImageBackground
                            style={styles.uploadStyle}
                            // resizeMode="contain"
                            source={
                              frontImage === null ? null : {uri: frontImage}
                            }>
                            <Image source={require('../assests/upload.png')} />

                            <View style={{paddingTop: 5}}>
                              <SubTitle
                                title="CNIC FRONT"
                                font
                                color="#06B2BC"
                                fontSize={14}
                                amount
                              />
                            </View>
                          </ImageBackground>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          activeOpacity={1}
                          onPress={takeBackFrontPhotoFromCamera}
                          style={styles.imageContainer}>
                          <ImageBackground
                            style={styles.uploadStyle}
                            // resizeMode="contain"
                            source={
                              backImage === null ? null : {uri: backImage}
                            }>
                            <Image source={require('../assests/upload.png')} />
                            <View style={{paddingTop: 5}}>
                              <SubTitle
                                title="CNIC FRONT"
                                font
                                color="#06B2BC"
                                fontSize={14}
                                amount
                              />
                            </View>
                          </ImageBackground>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={takeSelfie}
                        style={styles.singleimageContainer}>
                        <ImageBackground
                          style={styles.uploadStyle}
                          // resizeMode="contain"
                          source={selfie === null ? null : {uri: selfie}}>
                          <Image source={require('../assests/upload.png')} />
                          <View style={{paddingTop: 5}}>
                            <SubTitle
                              title="CNIC FRONT"
                              font
                              color="#06B2BC"
                              fontSize={14}
                              amount
                            />
                          </View>
                        </ImageBackground>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      width: '100%',
                      height: '20%',
                      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                    }}>
                    <Button
                      click={verify}
                      title={
                        steper === 'step' ? ' Verify CNIC' : 'Verify SELFIE'
                      }
                      backgroundColor="white"
                      marginBottom={15}
                      color="#06B2BC"
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => !modalVisible}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.map}>
            <Image source={require('../assests/map.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't see from your code sample where you are calling the second step "upload cnic picture". It seems that you are calling another modal on top of the first one.

If you have planned to have a full process within this modal, it is probably best to integrate a proper navigator rather than "navigate" between modals.

Comment: can you please add more details